# django excel xlwt

Tags: python, django, excel, xlwt

On a django site, I want to generate an excel file based on some data in the database.

I'm thinking of using [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt), but it only has a method to save the data to a file. How can get the file to the HttpResponse object? Or maybe do you know a better library?

I've also found this [snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1151/) but it doesn't do what I need. All I want is a way to get the stream from the xlwt object to the response object (without writing to a temporary file)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

neat package! i didn't know about this

According to the doc, the `save(filename_or_stream)` method takes either a filename to save on, or a file-like stream to write on.

And a Django response object happens to be a file-like stream!  so just do `xls.save(response)`.  Look the Django docs about [generating PDFs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/#complex-pdfs) with ReportLab to see a similar situation.

**edit:** (adapted from ShawnMilo's comment):

```
def xls_to_response(xls, fname):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/ms-excel")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % fname
    xls.save(response)
    return response
```

then, from your view function, just create the `xls` object and finish with

```
return xls_to_response(xls,'foo.xls')
```

Comment: thanks, I thought it should be something like this, I just didn't know where to look. I'll give it a try

Comment: This works great, but not until you figure out the syntax. The trick is to create an HttpResponse object and save the xlwt workbook to it.

Sample:
xls_response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/ms-excel")
xls_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=foo.xls'
            
xls.save(xls_response)
return xls_response

Comment: Your answer looks really great! But I'm just confused what his xls object is? Since it has a save() method, I thought it was "xls = xlwt.Workbook()", but this threw me 500 back, any help please? @Javier

Comment: What do I need to do in JavaScript to receive this `.xls` file in frontend?

Comment: "application/vnd.ms-excel" would be a better mimetype choice. Specifying `content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'` instead of mimetype would be even better.

Answer (score 6):

***UPDATE: django-excel-templates no longer being maintained, instead try Marmir http://brianray.github.com/mm/

Still in development as I type this but http://code.google.com/p/django-excel-templates/ Django excel templates project aims to do what your asking.

Specifically look at the tests. Here is a simple case:

```
#
from django_excel_templates import *
from django_excel_templates.color_converter import *
from models import *
from django.http import HttpResponse

def xls_simple(request):

    ## Simple ##
    testobj = Book.objects.all()

    formatter = ExcelFormatter()
    simpleStyle = ExcelStyle(vert=2,wrap=1)
    formatter.addBodyStyle(simpleStyle)
    formatter.setWidth('name,category,publish_date,bought_on',3000)
    formatter.setWidth('price',600)
    formatter.setWidth('ebook',1200)
    formatter.setWidth('about',20000)

    simple_report = ExcelReport()
    simple_report.addSheet("TestSimple")
    filter = ExcelFilter(order='name,category,publish_date,about,bought_on,price,ebook')
    simple_report.addQuerySet(testobj,REPORT_HORZ,formatter, filter)

    response = HttpResponse(simple_report.writeReport(),mimetype='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=simple_test.xls'
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save your XLS file to a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) object, which is file-like.

You can return the StringIO object's `getvalue()` in the response.  Be sure to add headers to mark it as a downloadable spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check [huDjango](https://cybernetics.hudora.biz/projects/wiki/huDjango) which comes fith a function called `serializers.queryset_to_xls()` do convert a queryset into an downloadable Excel Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-excel-response

Answer (score 0):

If your data result doesn't need formulas or exact presentation styles, you can always use CSV.  any spreadsheet program would directly read it.  I've even seen some webapps that generate CSV but name it as .XSL just to be sure that Excel opens it

Comment: I've also read somewhere that you can return an html file that excel can read, but I want to use formulas and styling, so that's no good.