# Serving a dynamically generated MS Excel files using django and xlwt fails in Internet Explorer

Tags: django, internet-explorer-8, xlwt

I am trying to use xlwt to create MS-Excel files from the contents of the database on my django site.

I have seen several solutions here on stackoverflow, in particular this link: [django excel xlwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883313/django-excel-xlwt)

and this django snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2233/

These examples work in firefox, but not in Internet Explorer. Instead of getting prompted to open or save a file, a bunch of wingding junk appears on the screen.  It seems that IE thinks the response is html.

Here is my view function:

```
def exportexcel(request):
    from xlwt import Workbook

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheetname')
    ws.write(0, 0, 'Firstname')
    ws.write(0, 1, 'Surname')
    ws.write(1, 0, 'Hans')
    ws.write(1, 1, 'Muster')

    fname = 'testfile.xls'
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/ms-excel")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % fname

    wb.save(response)

    return response
```

I am seeing this behavior in IE 8.

Any suggestions as to why this isn't working in Internet Explorer?

Thanks.

Comment: Try with `application/vnd.ms-excel` mimetype.

Comment: wow, that was fast and it worked. Thank you. Can you explain what 'vnd' does?

Comment: Look at my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mimetype you're using `application/ms-excel` is invalid for `.xls` files.

The standard one is `application/vnd.ms-excel`

Look here [*Setting mime type for excel document*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document) for more informations.

Comment: Nevertheless, the Content-Disposition header should have resulted in a Save prompt. OP should use Fiddler to look at the HTTP response headers to make sure that the header was being sent.