# Creating Excel using Django-REST-Pandas

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Background: I am using Django REST Framework (DRF) with Django REST Pandas (DRP) as the requirement is to have export to excel feature in the application.

Question: How to generate the excel workbook being downloaded by adding

1. Data with customized headers
2. Adding chart in the workbook
3. Adding worksheets.
4. Specifying name of file being downloaded

I am looking for small example (tutorial) links illustrating hooks in DRP to do the aforementioned tasks.

Why have I put this open question here?
Asking here as Google searches haven't given any worthy results so far. You can also recommend any better module than DRP which will be elegant to achieve the goals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Django REST Pandas by extending `PandasExcelRenderer` and overriding the `get_pandas_kwargs()` function.  This function can return any of the arguments for [DataFrame.to_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

```
class CustomExcelRenderer(PandasExcelRenderer):
    def get_pandas_kwargs(self, data, renderer_context=None):
        return {
            'sheet_name': 'Custom Name',
        }
```

*Edit*: the one special case is the first `to_excel()` argument (`excel_writer`), which is handled separately in `get_pandas_args()`:

```
class CustomExcelRenderer(PandasExcelRenderer):
    def get_pandas_args(self, data):
        writer = ExcelWriter(self.filename)  # Initialize with temp file
        # (Custom chart commands...)
        return [writer]
```

For changing the output filename you'd need to set a header in the view, probably by overriding the list() method:

```
class ExcelExportViewSet(PandasViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [CustomExcelRenderer]

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # (compute filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=' + filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for generating workbooks. Here is example code for Django to download file:

```
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook


def download_excel(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        filename = "XLS import.xlsx"
        wb = Workbook()
        response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type="application/ms-excel")
        response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error")
```

Comment: I have been using xlwt. Can I use the same instead of openpyxl? Any flip side of that?

Comment: Another simplier approach to download with xlwt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883313/django-excel-xlwt

Comment: These are all workarounds which doesn't make me use PandasViewSet & django-filters backend. I am more inclined towards a solution using Django-REST-pandas, parking openpyxl or xlwt as last options.